# Two mass system in a central force field

Tags: classical-mechanics

How does the potential of two bodies depend on their distance (i.e. relative position) but not their individual positions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question is regarding the "potential difference" between two objects that depends on their relative separation.

Potential is defined as the work done in moving an object of unit mass from a reference point to an arbitrary point (where the potential is evaluated) which is obtained as an integral: $$V(r)=\int_{r_0}^{r} \textbf{F}\cdot d\textbf{r}$$ where $r_0$ is the reference point.

Note that the scalar product inside the integral is a function of the radial component only.

Then when you evaluate the potential difference between two objects, the potential difference only depends on the radial separation between the objects. This is because the choice of the reference point is arbitrary (usually chosen to be at radial infinity) and the above integral is path independent.